# Form binding back with List of multiple select options

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I'am trying to bind model in spring form multiple select using Select2 jquery library
but selected options are always null,
first i display form correctly with the available options, then user can update (add or remove) other choice which i fetch them remotely with an ajax request.

i am using next dto to bind form data :
DTO :

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class MyDto{

    private List<Contact> agences;
    
    private Contact banque;
```

spring mvc form to display avaliable user option :

```html
...
  <form:select path="agences" items="${MyDto.agences}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" />
...
```

select2 initialization to format and fetch additional options with an ajax request
Select 2 :

```js
        $("#agences").select2({
            language: "fr",
            multiple: true,
            width: '100%',
            ajax: {
                url: "/fetchData.html",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        query: params.term,
                        banque : $("#IdBanque").val()
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                "id" : item.id,
                                "text" : item.name,
                            }
                        })
                    };
                 }
            }
        });
```

Controllor

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/update")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateIntranet(@ModelAttribute(value = "myDto") myDto, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest zRequest) throws JSONException {
   ....
```

the problem is when i receive the request i can't find selected options and the List is null

how i can  binding back the dto which include list of element using spring mvc

Comment: please share the relevant controller class